# mysql dump from specific tables that relate to each other

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my MySQL database.

I need to output **both tables to SQL dump files.** (CREATE scripts)

However, I may only dump **certain rows.** (e.g. where column = value).

This is **fine for the first table.**

However, the second table **may only dump rows where e.g. column = value that exists in 1st result set.**

I wanted to use mysqldump, however I don't think it will work for this type of query unless I do some sort of join or union ?

I can also use PHP and create the file while looping through the rows, however I don't think that is the most efficient way.

Any advise or help will be appreciated !

Comment: you can specify `where` clauses in mysqldump, but you'd have to do two separate dumps if the clauses are different for your two tables. `mysqldump db1 table1 --where ... > dump.sql ; mysqldump db2 table2 --where .. >> dump.sql`

Comment: @MarcB That's fine, however, the second where clause relies on the first. Thats my actual problem...

Comment: there --where clause can contain subselects: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@MarcB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) for answering the question, it worked 100%. I am posting this to follow stack overflow rules of answering and also to show what I ended up using.

So here is the 2 mysqldump commands I run inside of a bash script : (I replaced some private data with 'x')

```
#!/bin/bash

#dump the first table
mysqldump -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u xxxxx -pxxxxx --where="name='value'" databasename table1 > /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/table1.sql

#dump the second table that relates to the first one
mysqldump -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u xxxxx -pxxxxx --lock-all-tables --where="field_id in (select anotherfield_id from table1 where name='value')" databasename table2 > /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/table2.sql
```